# Convert mp4 to mp3

Tags: c#, vb.net, ffmpeg

I am looking for some library or code that will allow me to convert mp4 video to mp3.
I want it to be for free and compatible with the latest .NET framework (4).

Also, if possible, I am looking for a free ffmpeg wrapper than I can have in my vb.net application without trial or messageboxes.

If there is no free ffmpeg wrapper, can someone show me how to perform the conversion from mp4 to mp3 using command line and ffmpeg ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following code to process / execute ffmpeg command in vb.net.

```
 Dim _out As String = ""
 Dim _process As New Process()
 _process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
 _process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = True
 _process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True
 _process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = True
 _process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = True
 _process.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
 _process.StartInfo.FileName = "ffmpeg";
 _process.StartInfo.Arguments = " -i input.mp4 -vn -f mp3 -ab 192k output.mp3";
 _process.Start()
 _process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd()
 _out = _process.StandardError.ReadToEnd()
 _process.WaitForExit()
 If Not _process.HasExited Then
    _process.Kill()
 End If
 Return _out
```

In result you will receive ffmpeg output and mp3 audio file. For better encoding performance and parsing ffmpeg output i recommend using ffmpeg wrapper http://www.mediasoftpro.com/media-handler-pro.html

Comment: I get error on 
`_process.Start()`
Could not find file

Comment: you must provide complete path for ffmpeg

Comment: I did, I used openfiledialog to get the complete file path.
This is my code for the argument:
`_process.StartInfo.Arguments = " -i " & OpenFileDialog1.FileName & " -vn -f mp3 -ab 192k " & Application.StartupPath & "\output.mp3"`

Comment: ok you must use complete path for ffmpeg too.   _process.StartInfo.FileName = "Complete_FFMPEG_Path";

Comment: Oh okay, i fixed that, but now I get this from _out:
  Metadata:

    encoder         : Lavf52.111.0

  Duration: 00:00:37.27, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 934 kb/s

    Stream #0:0: Video: mpeg4 (Simple Profile) (DIVX / 0x58564944), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 29.97 tbn, 30k tbc

    Stream #0:1: Audio: mp2 (P[0][0][0] / 0x0050), 44100 Hz, stereo, s16, 128 kb/s

[NULL @ 03578100] Unable to find a suitable output format for 'Studio'

Studio: Invalid argument

Comment: @CodexVideos Try to add double quotes around the filepaths. It's been too long since I did VB.Net but in C#, it I would do String.Format("-i \"{0}\" -vn -f mp3 -ab 192k \"{1}\"", OpenFileDialog1.FileName, Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "output.mp3")). Where \" is how C# escapes the quote and Path is part of System.IO. String.Format makes it look a bit cleaner.

Comment: @CodexVideos issue may be in ffmpeg build or mp3 command. try simple command "-i -ab 192k out.mp3", if path include space then you must add quotation on both side.

Comment: @BlueVoodoo Thanks, it worked by adding the quotes!
MuhammadIrfan Thanks for the code, marked as the right answer!

Comment: How can we use this in a c# winform and get the Progression of the conversion ?

Answer (score 7):

You can just start a process (System.Diagnostics.Process) and hide the ffmpeg window if needed. The console output can be redirected to a StringBuilder or similar.

For the conversion, you can use something like

```
ffmpeg.exe -i input.mp4 -vn -f mp3 -ab 192k output.mp3
```

-vn is not required if your mp4 files has no video.